# Position of relative clauses and word order in the relative clause in sentences

Tags: word-order, relative-clause, subordinate-clause

I am learning relative clauses and I wonder if it is mandatory to place the relative clauses right after the word it refers to. Is it possible to place it elsewhere? Furthermore, how should the word order be in the relative clause(apart from verb being at the end of the sentence)? Is there are a rule to be obeyed in all subordinate clauses (**Nebensatz**)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do relative clauses have to follow the word they are describing?**

**No!** See the following:

> Ich sage Ihnen, dass das Pferd, *das ich gesehen habe*, lahm ist.
>   Ich sage Ihnen, dass das Pferd lahm ist, *das ich gesehen habe*.

**Is there a rule for verb order in subordinate clauses apart from having the verb last?**

**Semi-no!** Testing prompted me to actually allow every single of the 24 permutations I have listed below, (Thanks, Emanuel!) but they are defenitely more or less common and odd. See here (Numbers from 1 = totally common to 10 = severely odd, would make me stumble and re-read five times; according to my perception):

> […], weil mein Bruder morgen seinen Geburtstag in Leipzig feiert. (1)
>   […], weil mein Bruder morgen in Leipzig seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag morgen in Leipzig feiert.   (2)
>   […], weil mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag in Leipzig morgen feiert.   (2)
>   […], weil mein Bruder *in Leipzig* morgen seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil mein Bruder *in Leipzig* seinen Geburtstag morgen feiert.   (2)
>   […], weil *morgen* mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag in Leipzig feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil *morgen* mein Bruder in Leipzig seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil *morgen* seinen Geburtstag mein Bruder in Leipzig feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *morgen* seinen Geburtstag in Leipzig mein Bruder feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *morgen* in Leipzig mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (2)
>   […], weil *morgen* in Leipzig seinen Geburtstag mein Bruder feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* mein Bruder morgen in Leipzig feiert.   (5)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* mein Bruder in Leipzig morgen feiert.   (5)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* morgen mein Bruder in Leipzig feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* morgen in Leipzig mein Bruder feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* in Leipzig mein Bruder morgen feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *seinen Geburtstag* in Leipzig morgen mein Bruder feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* mein Bruder morgen seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag morgen feiert.   (2)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* morgen mein Bruder seinen Geburtstag feiert.   (1)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* morgen seinen Geburtstag mein Bruder feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* seinen Geburtstag mein Bruder morgen feiert.   (6)
>   […], weil *in Leipzig* seinen Geburtstag morgen mein Bruder feiert.   (6)

Note that I have labelled most options where the object (*seinen Geburtstag*) is before the subject (*mein Bruder*) as distinctly less common.
Feel free to disagree with my perception of commonness.

Comment: @Emanuel: I can't even disagree with you there so here are your 24 options. Feel free to disagree with the weighting (I'll just edit that in, quickly).